# Using anonymous types, to create unique keys, to look up controls in a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `MDIParent` that creates child `Forms` and fills them with `Controls`. I want to create a "tag" for each Control so that I can manage it/them better from my `MDIParent`.

The `Controls` are produced based on some data structure that the `MDIParent` owns. This data represents many physical circuit boards with inputs and outputs; there is one `Control` per IO contact. When an event is triggered in the `MDIParent`, passing new data along with it, I want to find the `Control` that this data should be written to.

To do this, when the `Controls` are instantiated I want to create an anonymous type and store it in a `Dictionary<AnonType, Control>` and then later on create a object of the anonymous type to lookup the specific `Control`.

So I would make my anonymous type and add it to the `Dictionary` like so.

```
int boardNumber = 1; int contactNumber = 27; 
var ctrlKey = { boardNumber, contactNumber };
aDict.Add(ctrlKey, aControlObject);
```

Then for lookup (when a new data event is triggered in my `MDIParent`) I will simple create a anonymous object in the same way (`var lookupKey = { boardNumber, contactNumber };`) and use it to lookup the `Control` in the `Dictionary` like so

```
Control aFoundControl = aDict[lookupKey];
aFoundControl.DoStuff();
```

Will this work? How would I initially define the `Dictionary`? This would be my first attempt at using anonymous types.

Comment: Use Tuples instead of anonymous types

Comment: Are `Tuples` only available in .NET 4.0? // My IDE (MVS) does not show anything for `System.Tuple` ... ? Any idea.

Comment: I'd suggest staying away from anonymous types for this. It may or may not work, but who knows if compilers will create anonymous types the same way in the future.  Just define a simple struct for your key, so that you have full control over the equality of your key.

Comment: Define an interface that implements your `DoStuff` method, use this interface as the type for the Value part of the dictionary and make sure all of the controls you want to add to the dictionary implement the interface.

Comment: *"Are Tuples only available in .NET 4.0?"* `Tuple` was introduced in .NET 4.0. Any particular reason why your software would be required to run on an outdated .NET version? Win XP?

Comment: I guess a struct would be a better choice // And yes, XP support.